# Ajax call to get list of objects clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I am trying to use an **AJAX** call to send data to my **django** view, which I then hope to use in another view. When a user clicks on a particular word, `known_words` must go up by one (this part works). But I also want to know which word the user clicked on (I have access to this in the template: `{{item.0}}`. And this is the part that I cannot get to work.

The relevant part of my **html** (this is the last column of my table, the first column contains `{{item.0}}`):

```
<a href="javascript:" class="word_known btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-word="{{item.0}}" data-songpk="{{song_pk}}" data-userpk="{{user_pk}}">Yes</a>
```

My **js**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var known_words = 0;
  var clicked_words = [];
  $(".word_known").click(function() {
    known_words++;
    var reference = this;
    var songpk = $(this).data('songpk');
    var userpk = $(this).data('userpk');
    var clicked_words = $(this).data('clicked_words');  //I know this part is wrong, how can I append the word to the list?
    $.ajax({
      url: "/videos/songs/vocab/known/"+songpk+"/"+userpk+"/",
      data: {known_words: known_words, clicked_words: clicked_words},
      success: function(result) {
    $(reference).removeClass("btn-warning");
    $(reference).addClass("btn-success");
    $(reference).text("Known");
  },
      failure: function(data) {
        alert("There is an error!")
      }
      })

});
})
```

**Views:**

```
def word_known(request, pk_song, pk_user):
    if request.method =='POST':
        pass
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        known_words = request.GET.get('known_words', '')
        clicked_words = request.GET.get('clicked_words', '')
        request.session['known_words'] = known_words
        clicked_words = []
        clicked_words.append(request.session['clicked_words'])
        print('The number of known words is {} and clicked words are {}'.format(known_words, clicked_words))

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(known_words))
```

In the console, when I click on a word (not 'hello'), I get the following in the console: 
`The number of known words is 1 and clicked words are ['hello']`

And if I click a second time on a different word: 
`The number of known words is 2 and clicked words are ['hello']`

So the counter is working, but not the word list. How can I fix that?

Comment: where is `clicked_words` in your `a` tag ?

Comment: `data-word="{{item.0}}"` is the word that is being clicked on

Comment: so `$(this).data('clicked_words')` should be `$(this).data('word')` change and see if that works .

Comment: @Swati Yes, you're right! Such a silly mistake, thank you. But the list is still empty! :(

Comment: @Swati Getting a weird response in the command line: `"GET /videos/songs/vocab/known/3/3/?known_words=1&clicked_words%5B%5D=%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B
B%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F HTTP/1.1" 200 41`

Comment: You can check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/2qsxucrw/1/) its working .Also you have used `GET` in ajax so the values are passing in url .

Comment: @Swati Yes, I see it's working there. Which must mean that the problem is with my `{{item.0}}` tag. But I can't find the problem, since it's working elsewhere in my template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217631/discussion-between-swati-and-mel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven’t tested this, but I think you are overwriting the Array instead of adding to it.

This line

```
var clicked_words = $(this).data('clicked_words');
```

Should be

```
clicked_words.push($(this).data('clicked_words'));
```

[This is a link to the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense and I've made the change. But now I'm getting an empty list... any idea what else might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Daniel Butler's answer, I had to change my view as follows:

```
clicked_words = request.GET.getlist('clicked_words[]')
```

Because apparrently when you send a list through jQuery it changes the keyword as well.